# The type initializer for 'Lucene.Net.Store.FSDirectory' threw an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to implement 'Lucene Search on my Asp.Net Core 2.0 Project.

```
 var dir = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:/test_lucene"));
```

I am getting the error

> "The type initializer for 'Lucene.Net.Store.FSDirectory' threw an exception and File not Found Exception".

While on Asp. Net Framework it is not giving any error.

Is there any alternative in Asp.Net Core?

Comment: Do you use [apache/lucenenet](https://github.com/apache/lucenenet)? If so, it is not supported for `netcoreapp2.0`, it only supports `.NET Framework`. If you want to use this in `.net core`, you will need to target your project to `net45`.

Comment: @TaoZhou lucene.net 4.8 not support asp.net core 2 ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to install nuget package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager into your project.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, I was having problems initializing a service that makes use of Lucene 3.0.3 on Net Standard, now is working